# MySql check for numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling to write a SQL statement - Im basically trying to distinguish between postcodes by checking if there is a number after the first letter.

For example i could have records with BL1 as postcode or B12, and when i enter in the search 'B' i only want it to select the records that have a numerical value after it - then if i search BL obviously that would just be a 'BL%' select.

With it being var char as well i'm struggling with this one, also its MySql.

Is it possible to convert then check the second char then condition it in mySql?

Thanks

Comment: Use php's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)? Explode them by spaces, then each array index will have its own condition - `WHERE column LIKE '%$string[0]%' AND '%$string[1]%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regular Expression

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE col REGEXP '^B[0-9]';
```

This matches only those values which start with B and have a digit next to it. If you want to expand the regex to also include alpha characters on second position you could do

```
WHERE col REGEXP '^B[0-9A-Za-z]';
```

**[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44088d/1)**